# Android: Unable to resume activity

Tags: android, exception, twitter, android-activity, resume

I am trying to integrate Twitter in my Application. I want a pop-up to be shown in which the user can enter his tweet.

Now when the user is already logged in, the application is working fine, but if the user needs to log-in first then the applications opens the twitter web-interface of login. From there, I am not able to come back to my application and show the 'enter-tweet' popup.

Please help.

```
Exception:
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {mad.android.MyTwitterApp/mad.android.MyTwitterApp.AndroidTwitterSample}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
04-02 00:16:53.511: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have a null pointer exception. Supplying the relevant code will help us to help you.